# HTML5 Multiple files upload using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, html

With HTML 5 i am trying to implement the file upload functionality. Now if i am uploading more that one file for which there are following two options.

- Single Request: Using singe AJAX    request i upload all 5 files.    Something similar like multipart    encoding.

|HTTP1Start-file1-file2-file3-file4-file5-HTTP1End|

- Multiples Request: For each  individual files i raise new AJAX   request.

|HTTP1Start-file1-HTTP1End|

|HTTP2Start-file2-HTTP2End|

|HTTP3Start-file3-HTTP3End|

|HTTP4Start-file4-HTTP4End|

|HTTP5Start-file5-HTTP5End|

My understating is that option two will be better and will also improve the upload performance.

Please let me know if that is correct or incorrect. Also let me know if there are any catches which should be taken care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary thing you need to be aware of is that not all browsers will support multiple-file upload within a single request. Hence, the latter approach is the only one that will work in all browsers.

Comment: right. But will multiple AJAX request provide advantage like faster uploads that single monolithic request ?